# Determine by java if a row has been manually deleted from mySQL databse tables

Tags: java, mysql, row

I have by Database in MySQL. I have my java codes. I used RSA algorithms for detecting if any data has been modified manually.

But now I have to modify the codes so that the java lines shall detect if any user has manually deleted a row from the tables.

Can this be done?

Do some lines of code exist that will show that rows for a specific date range has been deleted from MySQL tables?

Comment: So you want to see the difference between a manual delete (from sql) - versus delete by sql executed from within the java program?

Comment: Not really. I need to determine if a row from my account table has been deleted. If I can detect if a row is deleted, then I can conclude that the profit of the year is not the real profit.

Comment: you can detect deletions during runtime - by keeping the count of the total results, and then checking if the total has changed. I am not sure if there is a convenient way to do this in SQL though. You could create "snapshots" of the "row count" though, every X hours.